# How to append value to a state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, state

I am creating a Polls application in React, where you can ask a question, set some answers, and let people vote. I am using one state to keep the question, and one state to keep the answers. They are stored inside of an array, which holds objects (each object is individual question with its text, votesCount, etc.)

```js
const [question, setQuestion] = useState();
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
```

When the user enters text inside any of the inputs, I want to create a new object, and set a variable inside of to what they're entering.
What I've tried is something like this

```js
function appendAnswers (e) { 
    setAnswers([...answers, {text: e.target.value}]);
}
```

Here's what console.log(answers) outputs:

```js
{text: H}
{text: He}
{text: Hel}
{text: Hell}
{text: Hello}
```

It creates a new object on every user input, now my **question** is, instead of creating, how to append text to the object? Keep appending to text variable, and when user writes on a different Input, then create a new object, and so on. 
I know it's a little bit messy, and if there is a more simple solution to this, please let me know.
[image]

`

```
<span>Question    
   <StyledInput onChange={(e) => setQuestion(e.target.value)}></StyledInput> ?
</span>

<span className='answers'>Answer 1 
<StyledInput onChange={(e) => appendAnswers(e)}></StyledInput> 
.</span>

<span className='answers'>Answer 2 
<StyledInput onChange={(e) => appendAnswers(e)}></StyledInput> .  
</span>

<span className='answers'>Answer 3 
<StyledInput onChange={(e) => appendAnswers(e)}></StyledInput> 
.</span>
```

Anyway, this is the look and structure of the Form.

On user input, I want to update the state object field, and when user writes in a new Input element, I want to create a new object and keep it in the array.

Comment: Don't use an array. Use an object, and update at a different key for each input.

Comment: @JaredSmith could you help me with that a bit? If you can send a piece of code since it's confusing me..

Comment: You seem to be over-complicating this. `const [ans1, setAns1] = useState(''); <StyledInput onChange={(e) => setAns1(e.currentTarget.value)} />;` and do the same thing for all the other states/inputs. If you need something more complicated than that, then use `useReducer` and keep the states in one object. It's not really clear what problem you actually have here.

Comment: @JaredSmith Creating each state works too, but I'm planning to make functionality to dynamically add more answers, so that's why I chose adding new objects dynamically instead of hard coding states, but I'll do it for now